# How to structure data for prediction using rasters as targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, geospatial, raster

I'm looking to train a model using georeferenced rasters as the target variables. I am looking at some examples using pyimpute and scikit learn, but these examples all only use one target raster. Rather, I'd like to use several observations from different dates. Is there a way I could train using more observations? I'm trying to get my head around the code behind pyimpute here: https://github.com/perrygeo/pyimpute/blob/master/src/pyimpute/_main.py

I understand it uses each pixel as a target, but my problem is figuring out if, and how I can use several raster images. The examples I see here might use 6 explanatory rasters and one target raster, I would like to use say 6 explanatory rasters and one target raster for 10 different dates, so 60 explanatory rasters and 10 targets and still have it predict a response for each pixel. This seems difficult in the way the examples are structured in that there's a directory for the explanatory rasters which explain the one target raster in another directory.

Comment: Not sure about how gdal works in python, but this is pretty easily accomplished in R using gdal. Interestingly it looks like you're trying to do some kind of imputation. If things stay slow today, I'll throw up an example in R. Very good packages for dealing with rasters.

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim What I'm trying to do is expand on something I was looking at using one pixel. I was trying to predict the response of a pixel based on other explanatory variables like rainfall. The pixel was represented categorically. The end would be a prediction of the class of pixel. So it's more of a classification of each pixel than an imputation. But this classification is not just dependent on previous images, but also a number of explanatory variables. I wanted to increase the number of pixels I am predicting without looping through millions of pixels to train and predict.

Comment: Sure. Each pixel has n predictor variables. Each predictor variable is arranged as a band in a multiband raster. Then you develop a model to predict on that raster. In this is how you would take advantage of the decreased processing time associated with a raster. Easy to do in R, I do this with random forest models, imputation models, neural networks, etc.. regularly. Not sure how to build a model to predict on a raster in python. You ok with an R answer?

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim I think an R answer would be great. I have been looking at R as solution also, but I'm more familiar with python.